# screenshot black video image iOS webview app - cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a video inside a webview app.
At the moment I'm using the gitawego/cordova-plugin and when I take a screenshot, the image is generated but the HTML5 video element is saved with a black background (video element)
https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot

Thanks